# Ubuntu doesn't boot after UEFI installation

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi

I have tried to install Xubuntu 16.04 on my laptop with no success. Xubuntu = XFCE + Ubuntu so the instalation process and everything is the same as Ubuntu.

To sum up, I tried to install it and I wanted to delete my Windows and after Xubuntu was installed it didn't boot. If I plug the USB with Xubuntu and press try or install it gets stuck before booting. Help please!

**This is everything I have tried:**

When I bought my laptop it had installed a trial version of Windows. I wanted to install Xubuntu via UEFI and delete Windows. I might install Windows later along Xubuntu. What I did was the following:

I plugged the USB with the  64bit disk of Xubuntu in it. To boot from the USB I had to boot from Windows and then I clicked on an option that comes with Windows that rebooted the computer and booted from USB.

I followed this guide to install the OS https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

I followed the "General principles" of that link, but #2 because my BIOS doesn't have any option of   QuickBoot/FastBoot and Intel Smart Response Technology.

The installer appeared correctly and I selected the option of creating new partitions. I erased Windows and created two partitions. A small swap and the rest for `/` with the correct format. After, the installer told me that a boot partition was needed and its size should be ~35Mb I created one with format EFI of size 70Mb. The installation continued and after it finished the computer didn't boot.

A black screen with the text `Reboot or select proper boot device or insert boot media in selected boot device and press any key`. I guess something didn't work in the process of installation. I went into the BIOS and the devices to boot from were just from the internet IPv4 and IPv6.

Now if I plug the USB again the screen of the previous guide appears http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1347445084.png but if I press any option (and press <kbd>Esc</kbd> so I can see what is being loaded) it always gets stuck at some point.

I read somewhere that the boot partition needs normally ~600Mb so I thought that it was getting stuck because it hadn't enough memory. So,
I downloaded boot repair disk and erased all the partitions of my hard drive and formatted it completely. I wanted to install Xubuntu again from scratch. But I have the same problem, every time I plug the USB and press in try Xubuntu  or install Xubuntu it gets stuck.

I tried to install it without UEFI mode and I had the same problem. But something really strange happened. I enabled again UEFI and enabled secure boot and after I selected "try Xubuntu" it booted perfectly well. I thought "maybe I should have enabled the secure boot the first time and that was the only problem". So I rebooted in order to select Install Xubuntu but it got stuck again!!! After that I tried again to select Try Xubuntu and it got stuck too.

I don't know what more I can do. Could you help me to solve the problem? Ideally I would want to have Xubuntu installed in UEFI mode.

Comment: Did you hashcheck the downloaded ISO?  Did you ever run the media check option instead of "try or install"?

Comment: Please run the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/). This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Comment: I solved by pressing 'e' in grub and writing "nomodeset" before "splash" and then I could boot with the live usb. I could install it although the boot partition was not correctly linked in the bios. I solved this last problem with Boot repair.

Comment: @Damaru You should add your solution as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved by pressing `e` in grub and writing `nomodeset` before `splash` and then I could boot with the live USB. I could install it although the boot partition was not correctly linked in the BIOS. I solved this last problem with Boot repair.